# How to replace the � characters with "," from my string?

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to replace the � characters with ","

My actual string is:

```
String strMine = "HOUSTON SHEPHERD� A 4000 N SHEPHERD DR� HOUSTON� TX 77018.";
```

and my expected result is:

```
HOUSTON SHEPHERD, A 4000 N SHEPHERD DR, HOUSTON, TX 77018.
```

Comment: It sounds more like an encoding problem to me. Where did you get this String?

Comment: Why people on the earth have these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
strMine = strMine.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", ",");
```

You can use the pattern `[^\\x20-\\x7e]` in your String.replaceAll() method to replace all characters outside the printable ASCII range.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
String s = "�ss";
s = s.replace('�', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly encode the characters for your terminal.  [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop The Pain](http://bit.ly/unipain) has details.

**Change the encoding.** you should set the encoding to UTF-8. I believe this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that comma's don't show up normally... Did you copy your text from Facebook? I had the same strange problem when copying comma's from Facebook text into HTML. If yes, just remove comma's and replace them with new ones.

Every HTML character also has a less human HTML code; you can try replacing the comma's with
`&#44;`. For a complete HTML code reference: http://www.tedmontgomery.com/tutorial/htmlchrc.html

If you want to modify your string with PHP and keep the �'s, then

```
String strMine = "HOUSTON SHEPHERD� A 4000 N SHEPHERD DR� HOUSTON� TX 77018.";
strMine = strMine.replace("�",",")
```